# C# Registering Delegate in Interface throw Target Framework Error

Tags: c#, interface, delegates, .net-core-3.1

I am working on Azure Function `FunctionA` that is TargetFramework `netcoreapp3.1`. This `FunctionA` calls another project for services whose TargetFramework is `netstandard2.0`. In these service I have interface where I am trying to register `Delegates` but unable to do so and getting version error; reference below;

[image]

```
public interface ICustomerServices
{
    delegate Task<IEnumerable<string>> AppCustomerListHandler();
    Task<string> GetMyName();
}
```

Can I solve this problem without upgrading any framework

Comment: Why are you trying to declare the delegate within the interface?

Comment: i have static method which I need to do test.. so I have define delegate point to static method... this way I can mock delegate and test my static methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A delegate just describes the "shape" that some methods will conform to. It doesn't, in itself, describe an actual member of any enclosing type. If you want to *consume* a delegate within an interface, that's not a problem, e.g.:

```
public delegate Task<IEnumerable<string>> AppCustomerListHandler();
public interface ICustomerServices
{
    event AppCustomerListHandler AppCustomerListHandler;
    Task<string> GetMyName();
    void DoSomething(AppCustomerListHandler appCustomerListHandler);
}
```

Is just fine.